# Django request.user being inconsistent

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-1.6

I have a relatively simply override of the `save_model` method like so:

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    if not change:
        obj.created_by = request.user
        obj.last_modified_by = request.user
    else:
        obj.last_modified_by = request.user
    obj.save()
```

When creating a new record (`not change`), it populates `obj.created_by` with the string of the username, but `obj.last_modified_by` with the string of the user ID. I can mostly fix this by simply using `request.user.username` instead of just `request.user`, but it's odd to me that it does this inconsistently:

[image: inconsistent results]

Carl's user ID is 1.

In case you're wondering how `created_by` and `last_modified_by` are designed in the model, they are merely `CharField`'s (*not* `ForeignKey`'s):

```
created_by          = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=100, editable=False)
last_modified_by    = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=100, editable=False)
```

Why is it inconsistent?

Comment: What happens if you do: `user = request.use` and use `user` to update the `created_by` and `last_modified_by`?

Comment: @Tiago I don't understand. Is there a typo in your comment or did you intend to write `request.use`? I tried both `request.user` and `request.user.username`. I think what you're asking me to do is to just capture the username in a variable and then populate the fields from the variable, correct?

Comment: Yep, that is a typo. And yes, have you tried that? Depending on what happens, we can find out if request.user is being inconsistent or not.

Comment: @Tiago that seems to get the username consistently. Even so, why wouldn't two calls for `request.user` in the same context? And inconsistently at that? Fixing this isn't the problem (I simply can explicitly call `request.user.username`), I'm trying to get an *explanation* of the inconsistency.

Comment: My guess was that request.user is not a static field but a getter that is returning a different object the second time you access it. Each of this objects has a different "\_\_unicode__" or "\_\_str__" method that is being called when you do `obj.char_field = user`, the first time it returns the `username` and the second time the `id`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said it yourself.

> In case you're wondering how created_by and last_modified_by are designed in the model, they are merely CharField's (not ForeignKey's):

But `request.user` is an actual user instance (not a `CharField`). So you are setting the fields with the wrong thing.

You probably want to do something like `obj.created_by = request.user.username`.